# Finding a distance using -x

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, geometry

I have the next diagram.

[image]

In the picture, the distance from the positive charge $+q$ to the point $P$ equals $x-a$ and from $P$ to $-q$ equals $x+a$

The charges $-q$ and $+q$ are located on the points $-a$ and $a$, respectively.

Now I need to find the distance from the charges $-q$ and $+q$ to a point $Q$ located to the left of $-a$.

I guess that it is the same, $x-a$ and $x+a$.

But as $Q$ is located to the left of the origin of coordinates, I'd like to do it using $-x$ instead of $x$.

The distance from the origint to $Q$ would be $-x$ and the distance from $-a$ to $Q$ would be $-x-(-a)$, $-x+a$. And the distance from $+q$ to $Q$ would be $-x+a$, which is wrong.

How can I find these distances using $-x$?

Comment: How far to the left from -q?

Comment: Down to $-\infty$.

Comment: Distance from $-a$ to $Q$ is $-x-a$

Answer (score 1):

When an independent variable and a symbol are chosen distances remain the same in algebraic form. The variable $x$ is a displacement and can take any real positive or negative value by what we give to it to describe motion, for example. Holds good even for time rates as velocity and acceleration.